# kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted is showing up for one of my apps but not another on the same device

Tags: ios, core-location

I have an app i'm maintaining which recently stopped reporting users locations.  This is happening on many devices where it was previously working.  On my device I have determined that the auth status of CLLocationManager is kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted.  This stops the app from prompting for user permission.

I have no restrictions set around core locations and another app of mine running the exact same helper class to manage location works fine on the same device.  It prompts for user permission as it should.

Does anyone know anything that would cause kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted to show up besides restrictions?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this? I am seeing exactly the same problem on an iPad.

Comment: I just did some refactoring and it resolved itself.  It was probably a race condition.

Answer (score 5):

In the Settings app (in iOS 6) look under General, then Restrictions.  If Restrictions is enabled, then scroll way down to Privacy section.  This is where Restrictions are set for Location Services.

This is a different set of Privacy restrictions from the Privacy section that is on the first screen that can be locked with a passcode.

Comment: This isn't the issue.  Location services are enabled and working on the second app.  The first app never asks for permission even though location services are on.

Comment: Did you check the restrictions settings?  They are per app, so one app can work while another can be restricted.

Comment: Yes the issue is that my app never asks for permission to begin with and is not even listed in the restrictions settings.

Comment: You may want to check that your app ever calls startUpdatingLocation - otherwise, it won't be in the list of apps that wish to use location services.